# Skype4COM - Sent messages

Tags: c#, skype4com

What's a way for me to write the last sent message the current user has sent, because just for messing around I made a checkbox, named Italic, and when it is checked off I want each message the user sends to be sent with/or edited to  `"_" + text + "_"` since underscores around the text makes it shown in Italic.

Comment: There are events for when someone (even you) has sent a message, and I believe that you're able to edit a message via the API. I am not able to test anything at the moment, but you can play around little with the events and check all the properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
msg.Body = "_" + msg.Body + "_";
```

Of course, you need to create a program with this inside of it and a proper handler.  The following will accomplish this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SKYPE4COMLib;

namespace Italics
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Skype skype;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            skype = new Skype();
            skype.Attach(7, true);
            skype.MessageStatus += new _ISkypeEvents_MessageStatusEventHandler(skype_MessageStatus);
        }

        private void skype_MessageStatus(ChatMessage msg, TChatMessageStatus status)
        {
            msg.Body = "_" + msg.Body + "_";
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is a really late response, but hopefully you still have a use for this.